# Static mocked objects in JMockit

Tags: static, nullpointerexception, jmockit

Consider a test as below -

```
public class TestSomething
{
    @Mocked static SomeObject mocked;

    @Test
    public void testSomething()
    {
        new expectations() {{
            mocked.doSomething(); 
        }};

        callSomething(mocked);
    }
}
```

The issue is that mocked always turns out to be null because it is declared as static.
Can this be overridden?

Answer (score 1):

No, `@Mocked` and the other mocking annotations only apply to *instance* fields of the test class (and to test method parameters as well).